# Loop on Python: Index extension

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I have just started to learn python and I am having the following problem:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    A1 = (A['wap'][i]-A['wap'][i+1]) + (A['wap'][i+1])
```

The problem when the index is in the last element it will try to take the next element that doesn't exist. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `range(len(A)-1)`

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but in this loop all you're doing is assigning over and over to the variable `A1`.  This doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to limit the range of the for loop:

```
for i in range(len(A) - 1):
    A1 = (A['wap'][i]-A['wap'][i+1]) + (A['wap'][i+1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. It will take list element from 0 to last-1

```
for i in range(0,len(A)-1):
    A1 = (A['wap'][i]-A['wap'][i+1]) + (A['wap'][i+1])
```

Comment: Awesome! I actually did this and it work it! But I am not saving in an Array I believe because I tried to access it as a matrix and it doesn work

Answer (score 1):

you didn't mentioned , what you would add or subtract  while its the last element . if you don't add or subtract anything to the last element than you could easily get away with a if statement

> for i in range(len(A)):
>
> ```
> if (i<len(A)):
>     A1 =  (A[i]-A['wap'][i+1]) + (A['wap'][i+1])
> else  
>     A=A['wap'][i]
> ```

if you want to loop back and add  or subtract the very fast element to the  last element use :

> for i in range(len(A)):
>
> ```
>     A1 =  (A['wap'][i]-A['wap'][i%len(A)+1]) + (A['wap'][i%len(A)+1])
> ```

this will add  and subtract  A['wap'][0] to the very last element .

but you should not use  **for i in range(len(A)-1)** because then you are always ignoring the last element of the array .

Comment: Yes, this really works but now I realized that I only have one result in the end so I am not creating like a matrix. I tried to do this: A1[i][0] but I got an error

Comment: A1[i][0] wont work as your 2D array looks   like  A1["wap"][i] according to the code you submitted . so the **row index** is a string here 'wap' . post your array A as well , then I would be able to help you more .

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually my A is something like this:    5 columns composed by index, date from, date until, product and wap and 15 rows of values. I would like that my A1 would be an extension with the new values in a new column like results with the values that I just acquired in a column so just increasing my old matrix. so i wanna extend my original with the new values so they can be easily related.

Comment: check out the new comment i added . i guess i gave you what you needed . a quick tips :rather matrix start working dataframe . its much fun and easy

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> import pandas as pd // imports pandas package to create datsfranme  
> from IPython.display import display //  import display to display your dataframe 
> import numpy as np
> ```

create your dataframe with 5 columns and 5 columns

> ```
> A = pd.DataFrame({"index":[1,2,3,4,5], "date
> from":["1/2/2017","2/2/2017","3/2/2017","4/2/2017","5/2/2017"],
>               "date until":  
> ["1/3/2017","2/3/2017","3/3/2017","4/3/2017","5/3/2017"],
>  "product":["a","b","c","d","e"] , 
>                   "wap":[100,200,300,400,500] })
> ```

create the new column you need

> ```
>  A["wap_update"]=np.nan
> ```

display your dataframe

> ```
>  display(A.head())
> ```

```
 for i in range(len(A)):

    if (i<len(A)-1):

    A.at[i,"wap_update"] =  (A.iloc[i]['wap'] )+ (A.iloc[i+1]['wap'])
else : 

    A.at[i,"wap_update"]=A.iloc[i]['wap']

display(A)
```

A.iloc[i]['wap'] will get values at i row and "wap" column 
A.at[i,"wap_update"] will set the value at at i row and "wap" column

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot